# How do I encode a single image into multiple frames using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

I want to encode a *single* image for a set number of frames into an mpeg2 movie. i want it in mpeg2 so I can concatenate it later. I have tried:

```
ffmpeg -b 800000 -loop_input -i input.jpg -vcodec mpeg2video -vframes 30 output.mpg
```

But it seems to end up just one frame long and I'm not sure if it even has the correct codec.

Comment: Please show your complete ffmpeg console output.

Comment: How do you check the properties of the result video? It should be in MPEG-2 format, have 30 frames and 1.2 seconds long. If this is not the case, try the latest ffmpeg.